# Error: the program can't start because ImgProc.dll (third party library) is missing from your computer

Tags: matlab, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, mfc

I have three files `ImgProc.h`, `ImgProc.lib`, and `ImgProc.dll` created by Matlab. I imported them to my VSC++ 2012 MFC project, but when I ran it, the error occurred. I did add the `ImgProc.lib` into the `linker-> input->additional dependencies`, Copied 3 files into project directory.

I could not add references. Because when I tried, it was empty like:
[that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKEgH.jpg)

I really appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImgProc.dll` must be available at runtime in your application's directory. You need to manually copy this file to your output directories for both Debug and Release builds. Alternatively you can create a post-build step that does the copying. Having `ImgProc.dll` in your project directory is not enough - your project directory is not part of the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx).